# How to allow DOUBLE to take NULL value in mysql workbench when importing .csv dataset?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I was supposed to import a .csv file to the mysql using workbench.

However, at first it only load 100-200 row when there is 7.8k rows.
I realize that there is a "String" of a row that causing this problem. so I deleted " and now it load around 2k row. However, it still not all.

I realize when there is a blank cell in a column that expects a DOUBLE. It will cause error 1265.

so what is the solution so that MySQL will allow a blank cell in a DOUBLE column?

and also how do I allow " so that it won't mess up when I'm trying to import?

Edit:

```
The column and it data type is:
id - INT(PK, NN)
name - varchar(100)
host_id - INT
host_name - VARCHAR(45)
n_g - varchar(45)
n  - varchar(45)
la - DOUBLE
lon - DOUBLE
type - VARCHAR(45)
price - INT
minimum - INT
num_review - INT
Last - VARCHAR(45)
per_month - DOUBLE
count - INT
avaliability - INT
```

The error I'm getting for " is
`Row import failed with error: ('Incorrect integer value: \' Dalkey Avenue ."""\' for column \'host_id\' at row 1', 1366)`

```
example input: 
200979  "The Lodge, Dalkey Avenue ."    982970  Paul        Dn Laoghaire-Rathdown   53.2742 -6.10917    Entire home/apt 160 2   110 10/25/2020  3.4 1   0
```

Another error I'm getting is this:
`Row import failed with error: ("Data truncated for column 'per_month' at row 1", 1265)`

```
575339  Double Bedroom Close to City Center 1689834 Moris       Dublin City 53.34173    -6.23949    Private room    50  1   0           1   0
```

I have look into this error and I realize that when there is empty cells at per_month it won't load.
This is a successful import:

```
44077   cosy comfortable Irish cottage twin 193005  Teresa      Dn Laoghaire-Rathdown   53.28995    -6.25813    Private room    50  3   227 3/6/2020    1.91    3   0
```

Comment: Workbench is a tool, its mysql that is rejecting inappropriate data for column type

Comment: SHow us the data load command and an example of the input, INCLUDING all the bits that are creating anomalises, otherwise you will be just moving from issue to issue

Comment: Alternatively, if this is a One-Off load, just spend a few minutes fixing the CSV